# Как отследить прокрутку колесика мышки в px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться с `wheel`. Прочитал [статью об mousewheel](http://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel), автор которой утверждает, что

> Свойство deltaY – количество прокрученных пикселей по вертикали.

Но в у меня почему то так не выходит. Мне выдает число от 100-500, в зависимости от скорости прокрутки. Максимум что я могу отследить, прокрутку вверх и вниз.

Кто  то сталкивался с такой проблемой ? Как отследить прокрутку именно в пикселях?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('wheel', function(e){
        console.log(e.originalEvent.deltaY);
    });
})
```

```css
body{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: откуда уверенность, что это не прокрутка в пикселях?

Comment: То есть перемещение колесика на 1 деление равно 100 px ? А почему это значение постоянно обновляется?

Comment: вероятно так мышь работает, у меня значение всегда фиксированное и меняется только если поменять параметр вертикальной прокрутки в свойствах мыши.

Comment: А как это чисто пикселей складывать и отнимать?

Comment: с чем складывать и для каких целей?

Comment: обновляется, потому каждый раз заново вызывается событие. Можно и по одному пикселю прокручивать

Comment: У меня контентная область не скролится - `overflow: hidden`. Мне нужно при скролле, то есть в моем случае прокрутка колесика мыши, выполнять определенную анимацию. Хочу привязаться к прокрутке. Типа `if(scroll == 500){animate}else if(scroll == 1000){animate2}`. По сути мне не обязательно пиксели, просто читал, что именно пиксели есть у `wheel`

Answer (score 1):

> Мне выдает число от 100-500, в зависимости от скорости прокрутки

Ну и что вам не нравится? 
Это и есть пиксели, просто у вас прям мышка какая-то очень чувствительная, обычно дельта поменьше ( у меня в вашем примере выдавало в среднем 2-5 )

Положительное `deltaY` означает что мы прокручиваем вниз, отрицательное - вверх

Вообще, все зависит от св-ва [`deltaMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaMode), он отвечает за единицы измерения, в которых считается  `delta`

> DOM_DELTA_PIXEL (0x00) The delta values are specified in pixels.
>   DOM_DELTA_LINE (0x01) The delta values are specified in lines.
>   DOM_DELTA_PAGE (0x02) The delta values are specified in pages.

Comment: А это вообще непонятно. Почему у нас с вами разное значение, если оно в пикселях ?

Comment: @max потому что у меня мак и я использовал тачпад, у вас мышка со своими настройками

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.onwheel=({deltaY})=>console.log(deltaY);
```

Свойство `deltaY` - кол-во прокрученных **пикселей** по вертикали

Пример:

```js
let coll = {};

window.onwheel=({deltaY})=>{
    const newdown = (deltaY > 0);
    console.log(coll, newdown);
    if(coll.down === newdown) coll.sum += deltaY;
    else coll.sum = deltaY;
    coll.down = newdown;
};
```

- `coll.down` - движемся ли мы вниз
- `coll.sum` - на сколько пикселей движемся